# Recursive async delayed promise overlapping

Tags: javascript, recursion, scope, promise, closures

The use case is the following: I want to query an URL every X milliseconds until I get a positive reply.

I'm trying to achieve this in JS (node) and have an issue with multiple such requests.
If I start only one of those "chain calls" everything works fine.

But if I try to run  a number of those in parallel the "last one wins" (and the first one is never resolved). I seem to be using the reference to the same object or something, but I can't figure it out.

Note how the "masterCounter" and "id" variables get overwritten although they are passed as arguments by value.

Here is the working code(where "SECOND" wins over "FIRST"):

(you can run with node if you install request package https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)

```
var req = require('request');

const ASK_EVERY_MS = 500;
const AT_MOST_MS = 5000;

var childRecursive = (t, resolve, reject, t0, id, masterCounter) => {    
    var duration = process.hrtime(t0);    
    duration = (duration[0] * Math.pow(10, 9) + duration[1]) / Math.pow(10, 6)
    if (duration + t > AT_MOST_MS) {
        reject('timeout');
    } else {
        var options = {
            url: 'http://www.google.com',
            json: false,
            headers: {
                timeout: 1000
            }
        };
        callback = function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error) {
                console.log('body', body.substring(0, 100));
                if (masterCounter % 5 == 0) {
                    return resolve("success!!!");
                } else {
                    return childRecursive(ASK_EVERY_MS, resolve, reject, t0, id, masterCounter + 1, req);
                }
            } else {
                console.log('problem with submission GET request: ' + error);
                return reject(error);
            }
        }
        console.log(id + ' masterCounter is ' + masterCounter);
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(id + ' requesting...');
            req.get(options, callback);
        }, t);
    }
};

var t0 = process.hrtime();
var first = new Promise((resolve, reject) => childRecursive(0, resolve, reject, t0, 'FIRST', 101));
first.then(() => {
    console.log('FIRST done');
});
var scnd = new Promise((resolve, reject) => childRecursive(0, resolve, reject, t0, 'SECOND', 201));
scnd.then(() => {
   console.log('SECOND done');
});
```

and the output:

```
FIRST masterCounter is 101
SECOND masterCounter is 201
FIRST requesting...
SECOND requesting...
body <!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="hr"><head><meta content
SECOND masterCounter is 202
body <!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="hr"><head><meta content
SECOND masterCounter is 202
SECOND requesting...
SECOND requesting...
body <!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="hr"><head><meta content
SECOND masterCounter is 203
body <!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="hr"><head><meta content
SECOND masterCounter is 203
SECOND requesting...
SECOND requesting...
body <!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="hr"><head><meta content
SECOND masterCounter is 204
body <!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="hr"><head><meta content
SECOND masterCounter is 204
SECOND requesting...
SECOND requesting...
body <!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="hr"><head><meta content
SECOND masterCounter is 205
body <!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="hr"><head><meta content
SECOND masterCounter is 205
SECOND requesting...
SECOND requesting...
body <!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="hr"><head><meta content
SECOND done
body <!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="hr"><head><meta content
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the [implicitly global](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) `callback` variable. It needs to be

```
var callback = function (error, response, body) { /*
^^^ */
```

or

```
function callback(error, response, body) {
```

Always [`use strict` mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) to avoid such mistakes!